# Linux How to find list of variables of a process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I have multiple python process that executes with different environment variables. I am trying to create shell command that list the values with specific string

The line below (withou grep) show what I need - lines with environ content

```sh
pgrep python3.6 | xargs -t -I % sh -c 'cat /proc/%/environ' | sed 's/=/\n/g' | grep '.csv'
```

Example output:

```sh
sh -c cat /proc/8350/environ 
sh -c cat /proc/8351/environ 
sh -c cat /proc/8424/environ 
sh -c cat /proc/8426/environ 
sh -c cat /proc/8435/environ 
sh -c cat /proc/8441/environ
```

How do I feed that output into grep so as a result i will have output like:

```sh
sh -c cat /proc/8350/environ 
/home/data/file1.csv
sh -c cat /proc/8351/environ 
/home/data/file2.csv
sh -c cat /proc/8424/environ 
/home/data/file3.csv
sh -c cat /proc/8426/environ
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but try `grep -Paso '(?<==)[^\0]*\.csv(?=\0)' /proc/[0-9]*/environ` instead of that pipeline. FWIW, `xargs -t` will print the command line to stderr, not to stdout and because of that it won't go through the `sed` or `grep`.

Comment: @mosvy thank you! `xargs -t` is the issue in my script.
You script - is perfectly what I was trying to achieve.